# DLast function fixed on specific entry and not on the last one

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am completely lost why DLast function in my code finds not the last entry in the table, but specific one (8-th entry to be precise). Interestingly enough, code (seemed to be) working till entries count reached 10.

My code:

```
NrLast = DLast("Paraiskos_nr", "tblNew_sys") 'it should find the very last entry in the table
NewNr = Split(NrLast, "-")(1) 'since entry needed is in string, this part splits it and converts to integer number part of the string. 
NewNr = CInt(NewNr) + 1 'now its starts to generate new number by adding 1 to the extracted number from the last entry 
NewNr = "STV-" & CStr(NewNr) 'converts whole thing back to string in specific format 
Forms![frmNewSys_newEntry]![Paraiskos_numeris].Value = NewNr 'fills specific column with newly generated info on the new entry.
```

More info on my function: I am trying to create function which would generate sequential number in specific format for new entries in the table (they are added through special form). Number format is in string and it's like this "STV-XXXX" (x stands for number).

My code above seemed to be working, till entries number in the table reached 10 (failure on 10-th entry). Now every new entry gets generated number "STV-9". I tried to find the problem and it's seems to be the fact that `DLast` function in my code every time returns "STV-8" number. What causes that and how should I fix it?

Comment: Do you have an index sorting this field or others in the table?

Comment: Yes it sorted by ID which is auto generated by access and is unique, and as far as I can tell always increasing.

Comment: So maybe you need DLAST of the ID, and DLOOKUP nr from this ID? not sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Records have no inherent order. DLast and DFirst (as well as SQL Last and First) cannot be depended on to return perceived first or last record in table. Also, STV-10 will sort before STV-8. For correct sorting of alpha-numeric values, number part needs placeholder zeros: STV-0009 will sort before STV-0010. So DMax will then find the latest value. Or use DMax of ID and DLookup to get generated sequential value.

`DLookup("Paraiskos_nr", "tblNew_sys", "ID=DMax('ID','tblNew_sys')")`

Comment: That records have no order I figured out after reading MS Docks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dlast)  on DLast function. That function name mislead me at first... However your solution much more elegant than one offered in official docs (to create another query with single record  or to use  ADO Recordset (way to complicated for me)).